# How to set a size for a JPanel inside a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to put a JPanel in the center of a fullscreen JFrame with a defined size, but it's always stretching for the whole screen...

I tried `setBounds`, `setPreferredSize`, but they don't work.

This is the code:

```
public static void showScene(){
//Create the frame to main application.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Application"); // set the title of the frame
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);  // set the size, maximum size.
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create the panel to store the main menu.
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,200));
    panel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0,0,255));

    frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

}

public static void main (String[] args){

    showScene();

}
```

Comment: If you really want to force the size, then you can set the `PreferredSize` the `minimunSize` and the `maximumSize`. But a better approach would be using a Layout for your JFrame.

Comment: Override `getPreferredSize` of the component and return the size you want.  Call `JFrame#pack` to pack the window about the component.   You could use a different layout manager, like `GridBagLayout` which will honour the preferredSize of the components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BorderLayout` stretches the contents to fill the parent container.

If you want the child to have smaller size than the parent, use some other `LayoutManager` (try `FlowLayout`).

---

You can change layout using following code.

```
Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0,90)));

frame.add(panel);

frame.pack();
```

---

For further reference, follow [visual guide to layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Good luck.

Comment: when i change to frame.add(panel,FlowLayout.CENTER), the panel dissapears =/

Comment: You need to explicitly set the `LayoutManager`. Please check the edited answer.

Comment: Now, it dissapears again.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal component position
 at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
 at gui.showScene(gui.java:32)
 at gui.main(gui.java:43)

Comment: Ok, now i get: Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
   contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0,90)); and frame.add(panel); Thanks for the help.